# I am working on GA4 and getting brand value undefined for add to cart event

Tags: angular, google-analytics-4

My code as below:

```
addProduct: function(id, name, category, brand, variant, price, quantity, from) {
        dataLayer.push({
            ecommerce: null
        }); // Clear the previous ecommerce object.
        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'add_to_cart',
            'userId': userId,
            'ecommerce': {
                'items': [{ //  adding a product to a shopping cart.
                    'item_id': id,
                    'item_name': name,
                    'currency': "INR",
                    'item_category': category,
                    'item_brand': brand,
                    'item_variant': variant,
                    'price': price,
                    'quantity': quantity,
                }]


            }
        });
```

I have tried to add condition but not getting correct value. Please give me the suggestion to get the value of brand is present in admin and if the value is not present then it will show blank not undefined.
please suggest how to write condition for the same.